# How to Pop Drawer in Scaffold tree after Push

Tags: flutter

Scenario : From Home page, user can navigate to second page using the flex box lists on the screen or via drawer list.

However, the issue was if a user navigate to second page via drawer, and then pop back to previous screen, the Drawer will always expanded.

Referring to Widget Inspector picture, there is a layer for drawer under scaffold tree which I do understand it happened because of Navigator.push. So, how to i pop it once user access the the 2nd page via drawer and once user back to home screen, the drawer is minimized by default. Not Expanded as what currently happened.

Using Navigate.pushReplacementNamed is not working as the widget tree of MaterialApp will be completely removed, therefore user cant go back to previous screen using Back icon on AppBar.

Thanks.

[Widget Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee9jr.png)

Comment: use `Navigator.of(context).pop();` before push to newscreen use with `Navigator.push()`

Comment: @Assassin Post your solution as an answer

Comment: @NMAA please accept the answer, so this question can be considered complete.

Comment: ofcourse,i have post the answer@HarshvardhanJoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Navigator.of(context).pop();` or `Navigator.pop(context);` before push to newscreen will fix the issue

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const appTitle = 'Drawer Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('My Page!'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Screen 1'),
              onTap: () {
                 //close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => YourScreen(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Screen 2'),
              onTap: () {
              
                //close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => YourScreen2(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 Navigator.pop(context);
```

Before you made a push,or make a

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(newRoute);
```